# Intellij: Module vs Directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, directory, intellij-14

I have a Java Gradle project that I run within Intellij. Within it I created a `new module` however it is not being marked as a module, it is marked as a directory. See the [Intellij Icons](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html).

As a result I cannot create a run configuration in order to compile it. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run it, try a new project instead. File -> New -> New project from source
Then select your directory.